# Is there more than one different versions of the book Duafai Sagir (الضعفاء الصغير) from Buhari?

Tags: source-identification, reference-request, hanafi, sahih-bukhari, islamic-resources

In [this digital databas](https://lib.eshia.ir/40229/1/132/%22%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%88%D9%86%22#)e of the book Duafai Sagir (الضعفاء الصغير) from Buhari, I have found the following part in باب النون, in note 388, where Buhari express his strong critic against Imam Abu Hanifa:

> قال: كان ينقض الإسلام عروة عروة، وقال يعني الثوري: ما ولد في الإسلام مولود أشأم منه.

and

> لا يدخلها الدجال ولا الطاعون، وهو دجال من الدجاجلة

[image]

But if I open another digital database ([Wikisource](https://ar.wikisource.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B6%D8%B9%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1)) for the same book, Duafai Sagir (الضعفاء الصغير) from Buhari,the باب النون is shorter, it only goes up until point 384:

[image]

Is there more version of the book? Or was it censored because of the severe critic against Imam Abu Hanifa? Can somebody please explain that to me? Which version is accepted by scholars?

Comment: This needs some further investigation: indeed I found 3 versions: 1. by the editor Muhammad Ibraheem Zayd from 1986 in which looked like the one you've shared at the bottom starting the letter "noon" by #377, 2. edited by hafdih Zubair 'Ali Zai printed 2011: abu Hanifa is mentioned as #382 introducing the letter "noon" and 3. finally one edited by abu al-'Aynayn  first printed 2005: abu Hanifa introduces the letter but as #388. It could be that these editors based their editions on copies with differences. Note that al-Bukhari's position on abu Hanifa is known from some thrusts in his sahih.

Comment: Medi1Saif, thanks for your research! So if I understand it right versions: 1. by the editor Muhammad Ibraheem Zayd from 1986 and version 2. 2. edited by hafdih Zubair 'Ali Zai printed 2011 does not include this part:
قال: كان ينقض الإسلام عروة عروة، وقال يعني الثوري: ما ولد في الإسلام مولود أشأم منه.

But Version 3. edited by abu al-'Aynayn first printed 2005 includes it right?

Comment: can also version 3 be found online in scanned form (like this version: https://archive.org/details/TohfaTulAqvea_201408/page/n13/mode/2up)

or it is only available in digital database?

Comment: No only version 1 (printed 1986) doesn't include the statement on Abu Hanifa. I found version 3 in a-Shamela so far.

Comment: Medi1Saif thank you for your research. Can you also send the link where you find Version 2, edited by hafdih Zubair 'Ali Zai printed 2011?

Comment: Version 1 edited by Muhammad Ibraheem Zaayid is [here](https://waqfeya.net/book.php?bid=2455) or [here](https://shamela.ws/book/10542/103). version 2 edited by hafidh Zubair 'Ali Zai can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/TohfaTulAqvea_201408/page/n113/mode/2up) and Version 3 edited by abu al'-Aynayn can be found [here](https://shamela.ws/book/8632/126). One remark the manuscript which is attached to wikisource is "blacked" at the beginning of the letter "noon" page16/20 and one can read a deviation there already in between the black ink and the first readable name is النضر بن منصور

Comment: The authors of wikisource displayed a different scanned mansucript than the one they've transmitted as a text. Since the manuscript looks like it was containing the name of abu Hanifa, since between the black one can read the statement "قال: إن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال" from the biography snippet of abu Hanifa which is mentioned in other versions.